# updating value within object using "this"

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to update a value from within the object itself. I have the following code:

```
    var stepData = {
        0: {
            ref: "Home",
            values: {

            },
            init: function(){
                stepData[1].ref = 'new value';
                alert(stepData[1].ref);
                return;
            },
            save: function(){

            }
        },
        1: {
            ref: "one"
        }
     }

    $("#run").click(function(){
        stepData[0].init();
    });
```

Which works fine. However, I can't replace

```
stepData[1].ref = 'new value';
alert(stepData[1].ref);
```

with

```
this[1].ref = 'new value';
alert(this[1].ref);
```

Why not?

**EDIT**: sorry, mistake in original code. Fixed now.

Comment: `this` only works like that for object constructor functions. Also, in jQuery event handlers, `this` will always refer to the selected DOM element.

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Comment: It doesn't work because if you call `stepData[0].init()`, then `this` refers to `stepData[0]`, not `stepData`.

Comment: Ah, ok, i see. So the way I've got it is OK then?

Comment: @DJDavid98: *"`this` only works like that for object constructor functions"* No, that's not true at all. `this` is basically just a special function argument, it can be used anywhere for anything. It's quite commonly used in non-constructor functions (such as those attached directly to an object).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "like that" was supposed to mean in this case.

Comment: @DJDavid98: `var a = {answer: 42, say: function() { console.log(this.answer); }}; a.say();` `this` isn't tied to constructors at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is set primarily by how a function is *called*, not where it's defined. Your code:

```
$("#run").click(function(){
    stepData[0].init();
});
```

...calls `init` with `this` set to `stepData[0]`.

You *can* call it with `this` set to `stepData` if you like, using `Function#call`:

```
$("#run").click(function(){
    stepData[0].init.call(stepData);
});
```

From your comment on the question:

> So the way I've got it is OK then?

Yes, as long as `stepData` is a singleton, there's no particular need to use `this` in its functions.

More about `this` *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because if you call `stepData[0].init()`, then `this` refers to `stepData[0]`, not `stepData`.

One way to improve the situation is to use an immediately invoked function to create your object:

```
var stepData = (function(){
    var mySelf = {
        0: {
            ref: "Home",
            values: {
            },
            init: function(){
                mySelf[1].ref = 'new value';
                alert(mySelf[1].ref);
                return;
            },
            save: function(){

            }
        },
        1: {
            ref: "one"
        }
    };

    return mySelf;
})();
```

The following will break the code that you have now:

```
var newVariable = stepData;
stepData = null;
newVariable[0].init();
```

but it will not break the approach above.